Fixing Panasonic microwave after brownouts?
I have a relatively new Panasonic Genius 1250W microwave. Lately, we've had tons of brownouts due to issues with our power grid.
Yesterday, it just stopped working. The numbers don't turn on, so even if it's plugged in, it looks like it's unplugged.
Is there a relatively easy way to fix this? It's relatively new and it's in almost-new condition.
Also, the outlet where the microwave's plugged in has electricity since there's another small appliance connected to it.

Has power surge fried the circuit board? Is your home surge protected?

Do you mean the microwave's circuit board? The outlet where the microwave's plugged in has electricity.

Does relatively new might mean it is still in warranty?  Or did it lapsed two days ago?  Today's stuff usually does not play nice with brown outs/surges.

"Relatively new" means that it's a year old, at most. It's definitely not new.

@rbhat yes the microwave's circuit board. I would expect that you still have power at the outlet because outlets can usually handle power surges. The prime suspect is the microwave. You can sometimes diagnose this through visual inspection - the circuit boards actually look like something exploded somewhere.

Got it. I looked at the back of the microwave and nothing seems burned. The microwave never had a "burn" smell, as if something had exploded.

With small electronics (and in the case of the control panel of a modern appliance, the electronic components are very small), a failure - whether repetitive damage leading to failure or a single surge - can "fry" parts that are so small you wouldn't know it except by tearing everything apart and looking for teeny tiny burn marks.

Microwave ovens typically have a series of interlock switches that provide safety to keep the oven from operating if the door is open, ajar or misadjusted. These interlocks are often designed to short out an internal power line fuse across the power input to purposely blow the fuse.
It may be possible that a power surge, especially if it happened while the the user was interacting with the microwave, caused the internal circuitry to falsely detect a safety interlock and caused the power fuse to blow.
You may want to check if such fuse in your oven is blown open preventing any of the oven's internal circuits from receiving any power.

This.  My folks had a microwave that stopped working; replacing the internal fuse solved the problem.

TL;DR If under warranty, get Panasonic to replace, otherwise toss it.
Brownouts, surges (often there are surges as power is returning to normal following a brownout or outage, and sometimes due to other reasons) and other problems with electric power can easily mess up any electronic circuitry. In the case of a microwave oven, the control panel is always on, even when you are not cooking, so it is quite vulnerable to these types of problems.
While a typical computer power supply will often be designed for a wide range of voltage (e.g., 100V to 240V), an appliance designed for 120V will generally not need to handle more than +/- 10% variance (108V - 132V) and, as a result, may be designed to simply not deal with extended brownouts (< 108V) or surges (> 132V) very well.
If 99.9% of users will not have the problem, it is not worth the extra $2 it would add to the cost of every appliance to handle those problems more effectively. Manufacturers of mass-market products, particularly appliances, look at the cost of every component very carefully and remove anything not absolutely needed. That $2 component cost saved by using a cheaper power supply module might result in a $10 lower retail price, which can result in many additional units sold. While some customers will carefully examine many different attributes of an appliance before selecting one (though power supply quality is generally not one of those listed attributes, except in some high-end computer systems), an awful lot of customers will go into their local Costco/Walmart/Target/etc. (or online Amazon) and look for "cheapest microwave oven at least 1.5 cubic feet" or some similar basic search (whether online or in person) and if the Panasonic costs $10 less than the alternative, that's the one they buy.
Note this is not a complaint about Panasonic - I have many of their products including (I just checked) the exact same model of microwave oven. This is common to all major mass-market consumer appliance manufacturers, with the exception possibly of the very high-end.
The secondary issue is that most consumer portable/plug-in appliances, with the exception of some "built in" appliances that happen to be plug-in (e.g., some microwave oven/hood combinations or appliances such as dishwashers or disposals that can be plug-in or hardwired but designed to be fixed in place, or of course washers and dryers which are "major" appliances that happen to usually be plug-in) are simply not designed to be repairable. They can be repaired but the cost of components is relatively high and the designs are such that they simply aren't easy to fix. That isn't so much to force replacements every 'x' years (after all, you might buy the replacement from a different manufacturer) but because it is cheaper to manufacture things that way. In addition, there are some serious safety issues when it comes to a microwave oven. I have replaced safety switches (interlocks) on a combination microwave oven/hood (interesting story...) but a typical countertop oven has those switches hidden not behind screwed in panels but behind glued on plastic.
The control panel is even worse. Unlike many smaller/simpler components, the control panel for most modern computerized appliances is only available from the manufacturer and typically at a high multiple of the original cost (there are a bunch of reasons for that). So a $250 microwave oven with a control panel that costs $20 in original build might be sold for $60 as a replacement. But it generally isn't even available as a replacement (unlike for larger appliances) because by the time you add that $60 to the (ballpark) $100 you need for a professional installation (no manufacturer will want to hear about DIY installation of safety-sensitive items, which is absolutely the case with almost anything in a microwave oven), you are now at well over half the retail replacement cost. Which means most people (except adventurous DIYers) won't bother, so they don't even sell it.
Which gets to the final answer:

If under warranty, contact Panasonic. You have a good chance of them replacing it with an equivalent new or refurbished model at no charge.
If not under warranty, time to get a new microwave oven.


Also add a whole-house surge protector, if you own your house, and a good high-joule plug in surge protector for tne new oven. The whole house surge protector will help but may not catch intermediate surges, so the plug-in protector picks up. Security in depth... (Note that no surge protector will stop a direct lightning strike, or a car hitting your power pole and making the 13kV distribution wire drop on the 240V lines feeding your house.)

Thirdly, if the panel space is simply not available, you can surge protect at the receptacle (for key appliances like washer, dryer, dishwasher, refrigerator, etc.) or on a purpose built power strip (computer, router, modem, TV, stereo). You should assume absolutely every electronic is surge vulnerable.
